# Translating Maggid Mishneh (Issurei Biah 12:10)

Tags: hebrew, rambam, translation, mishneh-torah

My [previous](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117166) [three](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/117767) [questions](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/118005) on this topic dealt with the [Rambam's original text](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah,_Forbidden_Intercourse.12.10), touching upon matters of both [translation and interpretation](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/960660/jewish/Issurei-Biah-Chapter-Twelve.htm#v10), the two being inexorably linked; in this follow-up, however, we will inquire about one of its earliest commentaries, contained in the [Maggid Mishneh](http://www.sefaria.org/Maggid_Mishneh_on_Mishneh_Torah,_Forbidden_Intercourse.12.10):

> זה לא מצאתי מבואר והפסוק הזה אינו מוכרח דהתם אפילו לא נבעלה כיון שהיו ראויות לביאה היו נהרגות כמו שמפורש ביבמות בפרק הבא על יבמתו ויהיה הטעם מפני שעל ידיהן עבדו ישראל לפעור ומתו מהם רבים. ומ״ש בסנהדרין פרק ד' מיתות (סנהדרין דף נ"ה) גבי בהמה שהיא נסקלת משום שבאת תקלה לישראל על ידה ושקיל וטרי התם אי נסקלת בקלון בלא תקלה היינו בבהמה אבל בכותית לא אשכחן ואיכא למימר שדעת רבינו דכיון דבנשי מדין אשכחן דאפילו ראויות לביאה נהרגו משום שבאת תקלה על ידן איכא למילף מינייהו בעלמא בנבעלה במזיד

whose untranslated Hebrew text an online acquaintance rendered into English as follows:

> *I did not find this explained, and this verse is not necessarily from there <sup>(Numbers 31:16-17)</sup>: even if she had no sexual intercourse, nevertheless, because they were worthy <sup>(cap)able ?</sup> of sexual intercourse, they were still killed, as explained in [Yevamot](http://www.sefaria.org/Yevamot.60b.6-8), in the (sixth) chapter, entitled "Haba Al Yevamato"; and the reason for this will be that, because of them (the Yevamatot), Israel worshiped Peor, and many (Israelites) died because of them. And what is said in [Sanhedrin](http://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.55a.12-19), Chapter 4, Deaths (Sanhedrin, page 25) about an animal that is stoned because it brought an obstacle.*
>
> ארמית
>
> > יֵשׁ כַּאן ללמוד מֵהֶם בעוֹלָם בנבעלה במזיד
>
> *Aramaic:*
>
> > *We need here to learn from them that <sup>are ?</sup> in the world <sup>(?)</sup> if she had sexual intercourse intentionally.*

My request to the community would be to ascertain whether, or to what extent, the English translation above represents a complete and/or accurate rendition of the original Hebrew text:

- If incomplete, which phrases were left out, primarily due to the linguistic difficulties encountered, relating to the discrepancies between the modern Israeli standard *versus* historical variants and/or regional dialects of Hebrew?
- If (partly) inaccurate, what corrective suggestions would one propose to improve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few lines of the text are left out in the middle until the last few words. A correction of what was already translated together with the rest (my own changes and additions italicized):

> I did not find this explained, and this verse is not *a necessary proof, because* there (Numbers 31:16-17), even if she had no sexual intercourse, nevertheless, because they were *capable* of sexual intercourse, they were still killed, as explained in Yevamot, in the (sixth) chapter, entitled "Haba Al Yevamato"; and the reason for this *would* be that, because of them (the *Midianite women*), Israel worshiped Peor, and many (Israelites) died because of them. And *as for* what is said in Sanhedrin, Chapter *"Four Deaths"* (Sanhedrin, page *55*) about an animal that is stoned because it *was the cause of a sin*, *where it argues back and forth over there whether it's stoned if it was the cause of shame but not a sin, the discussion is regarding an animal, but we never find such a discussion about a gentile woman. And it's possible to answer that the Rambam's opinion is that since we find regarding the Midianite women that they were killed even if they were capable of intercourse, because they caused a sin, it's possible to derive from this case elsewhere if someone had sexual intercourse with her* intentionally.

The Maggid Mishne adds immediately afterwards (not in the Hebrew text in your post) that this isn't entirely clear to him.

Comment: Yes, I focused on 12:10:1, specifically.

Comment: Off topic, but important: Could you let [this user](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/25486) know that [his question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/126119) has been [answered here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/86194/) ?