# Does 4 Ezra (2 Esdras) teach the divinity of Ezra?

Tags: history, apocrypha

In an [article](https://otp.wp.st-andrews.ac.uk/abstracts-lectures/the-book-of-6-ezra-2-esdras-15-16/) by the University of St. Andrews about the Book of 6 Ezra, it is stated:

> In the Syriac text of 4 Ezra 14:48 (and the versions that derive from
> it) there is a brief account of the ascent and apotheosis of Ezra
> which is missing in the Latin of 2 Esdras.

I am currently trying to find out where this is found. The only place in 4 Ezra where I could find anything similar to this is 4 Ezra 2:42-48

> I Esdras saw upon the mount Sion a great people, whom I could not
> number, and they all praised the Lord with songs. And in the midst of
> them there was a young man of a high stature, taller than all the
> rest, and upon every one of their heads he set crowns, and was more
> exalted; which I marvelled at greatly. So I asked the angel, and said,
> Sir, what are these? He answered and said unto me, These be they that
> have put off the mortal clothing, and put on the immortal, and have
> confessed the name of God: now are they crowned, and receive palms.
> Then said I unto the angel, What young person is it that crowneth
> them, and giveth them palms in their hands? So he answered and said
> unto me, It is the Son of God, whom they have confessed in the world.
> Then began I greatly to commend them that stood so stiffly for the
> name of the Lord. Then the angel said unto me, Go thy way, and tell my
> people what manner of things, and how great wonders of the Lord thy
> God, thou hast seen.

Is this the account of the ascent and apotheosis of Ezra, or is the article speaking about something else?

Comment: This work is not canonical in our Jewish tradition.

Comment: I don't understand the logic here. How is a question about Jewish Apocrypha off topic?

Comment: This site isn't about Jewish history, it's about Judaism. I agree that apocrypha is a fine line, but if it's not being used to understand mainstream Judaism in some way, it's usually seen as off-topic here (IIRC).

Comment: Not long ago I asked about the site's stance on the topic of apocryphal questions: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5404/mys-stance-on-questions-concerning-apocryphal-texts the subject still hasn't been worked out satisfactorily. If we were to go by the answer given on Hellenistic Judaism, then I see no reason for this question to have been closed. But it seems that not everyone accepted that suggestion...

Comment: FYI, this question was reposted on the [hermeneutics.se] site: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/69290/2757

Comment: Hi, you can fine an answer to your question here: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/69290/32555

Answer (score 2):

The book of Ezra does not have multiple volumes. The chapters of the book of Ezra do not have anything close to what you cite. This article is about some other religion that does not have anything to do with Judaism. Indeed the quotation that you cite implies idol worship.

Comment: I understand that 4 Ezra is apocryphal.

Comment: Apocryphal definition is - of doubtful authenticity : spurious. Thus it is to be treated as an obvious forgery and completely false. @user44810

Comment: to deny it is canonical scripture is one thing. But it is still a part of Jewish history and is thus of immense value.

Comment: Based on the citation it is post Xian and as such has nothing to do with Judaism. It is like saying *the new testament* or the *quran*  are involved with *Jewish History*. In either case they have nothing to do with Judaism and there are no questions on them that would be relevant to this site @user44810

Comment: @sabbahillel Are you suggesting that anything post-Christianity has nothing to do with Judaism? Like the mishna and gemara?

Comment: No. I am saying that something pretending to be *scripture* that is post xianity is invalid. Mishna Gemorah rishonim and acharonim do not pretend nor do they write in an idolatrous manner. Each document is analysed on its own. This citation is one of the spurious writings that is an obvious fake. @magicker72